# VB.NET inheritance IntelliSense phantom member

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

I have a set of generic classes, set up to represent data in a database recordset/datatable (collectionclass) with a sub object representing a row (rowclass). These are then inherited for representations of specific tables. For some reason when I use these inherited objects I am suddenly seeing a new member in IntelliSense: `$VB$ClosureStub_get_RowCount_MyBase` on an instance of an implemented collectionclass(recordset/datatable). It does also contain the properly listed `Public ReadOnly Property RowCount` that doesn't actually exist in the implemented middle class existing only because of the inherited base class code.

[image: new unknown member function mysteriously appearing]
[image: the rest of the member properties/functions with one seemingly related to the strange one selected]

This shows the complete list of members of an example inheriting class, which only contains `Public Shadows Function GetRowClass` `Public Shadows Iterator Function RowClasses()` and a real function `Public Function GetTermString`. All other members are derived from either the inherited base class or the .NET framework itself(`Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType`, `ToString`). `$VB$ClosureStub_get_RowCount_MyBase` does not exist in either.

This only started showing up recently, and nothing of consequence regarding the inherited class or the implementation class has really changed except a recent recompile for other fixes recently took place in the base class of course requiring a recompile of the implementation class. What does this mean? Why did this start showing up? Any help understanding this would be appreciated!

Comment: Got a screenshot or several?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If I take this method:

```
Sub Main
    
    Dim i As Integer = 42

    Dim f As Func(Of Integer) = Function()
                                    Return i * 2
                                End Function
        
    Console.WriteLine(f())
    
End Sub
```

And look at the IL produced I get this:

```
.method public 
    instance void Main () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20ca
    // Code size 35 (0x23)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void '_Closure$__2-0'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: ldc.i4.s 42
    IL_0008: stfld int32 '_Closure$__2-0'::$VB$Local_i
    IL_000d: ldftn instance int32 '_Closure$__2-0'::_Lambda$__0()
    IL_0013: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0018: callvirt instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<int32>::Invoke()
    IL_001d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0022: ret
}
```

Note that there is a local variable called `$VB$Local_i`. This is how VB implements closures.

What you're showing is a similar closure.

What's unclear is why it is showing up in intellisense.